# Disable automatic switching to 4G from WiFi which doesn't have internet connection

Tags: iphone, wifi, airplay, 4g

Have iPhone which is connected to WiFi network which doesn't have access to internet. iOS apparently detects that there is no internet and tries to disable WiFi for a short period of time and connect to 4G.

Noticed it because iPhone is connected to AirPlay device and music is stopped every ~15 minutes and when I check the connection I see 4G, but not WiFi.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Do you want your iPhone to use the 4G LTE **and** the no-internet WiFi network at the same time?

Comment: That's interesting.  I have often lamented what I thought was an Apple design error—if there's a WiFi connection, my iPhones have always refused to use cell data, even if the WiFi router has no internet.

Answer (score 1):

Put your iPhone into Airplane Mode to disable the cellular connection. Then re-enable Wi-Fi networking (you can do this even in Airplane mode). This will cause it to stick with the Wi-Fi network.